# JTable using Swing

Tags: swing

HI,
 I am new to programing world. I want to know how to generate dynamic table using java swing component. I like to know how rows are generated dynamically where column remains fixed.
Please anybody can help me out

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the 'official' table tutorial:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_examples/javax/swing/table/

Answer (score 0):

Everything you ever need to worry about is in your table model. Understand what an AbstractTableModel is, implement your own, and then you should be fine.